# Concatenation in Linq-to-Entities / Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I want to perform the following task in Linq-to-Entities that can be done easily in SQL. Please help in this regard.

```
select 0 as eid, 'Select' as eName

union

select eid , empcode + '' + empname as eName 
from tblemp
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483711/union-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 0):

This is even easier than the link coined by Meysam.

```
CoreUtil.ToEnumerable(new Employee { Name = "Select" })
    .Concat(context.Employees.AsEnumerable())
```

where `ToEnumerable` is a very useful little function you'll use more often:

```
public static class CoreUtil
{    
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(params T[] items)
    {
        return items;
    }
}
```