# Getting unique rows from multiple tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have multiple tables that have a userid guid field t hat is unique. I need to get a DISTINCT count of the userids of all all rows across all of these tables. I also need to access this count within a controller. How would I do this in entity framework? Or would it be better to use a stored procedure of some kind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the UNION keyword?

```
SELECT guid FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT guid FROM TABLE2
UNION ....
SELECT guid FROM TABLEN
```

Refer: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Note that UNION always chooses distinct values. So, you should be good.

You can simply get the count using query nesting.

```
Select count(City) FROM
(SELECT City FROM Customers
UNION
SELECT City FROM Suppliers
ORDER BY City);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I use this in a controller with the entity framework?

Comment: Are you using entity SQL?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399797.aspx


Here is an example in C#
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483711/union-in-entity-framework