# Query a subset of an entity and cast it into another model using EF 6

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I want to be able to query a subset of an Entity into another model. For example, say I wanted to pull contact information from multiple models and return a contact model. This is just an example:

```
public class Store
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    ...
}

// Not an entity
public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Type {get; set; }
}
```

I want to query just ID, Name and Phone from both Store and Person. Union the results together and have it strongly typed as Contact to pass to my view. Type and ID together would server as a reference back to the original Entity so I can do some CRUD operations.

Is this possible with EF 6? A better way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
dbContext.Stores.Select(s => new Contact 
    {
        ID = s.ID,
        Name = s.Name,
        Phone = s.Phone,
        Type = "Store",
    })
    .Union(dbContext.Persons.Select(p => new Contact 
    {
        ID = p.ID,
        Name = p.Name,
        Phone = p.Phone,
        Type = "Person",
    }));
```

(with some assumptions about your `DbContext` and `DbSet` names).

See [Union in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483711/union-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Works perfectly! Easier than I thought. Still getting my mind wrapped around using Entities. Thank you very much for your fast answer.