# How to use union in Entity Framework with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I have two variables `Income` and `Expense`, I want to union this two variables and put the result into a `sumSalary` variable, but I always get an error (the error in `sumSalary` at `Income`). Please help me solve this problem.

```
public void PayrollReport()
{
    var income = employeeList.SelectMany(a => a.IncomesModel,(a,b) => new 
            {
                a.Salary,
                a.HolidayAllowance,
                EmployeeNik = a.NIK,
                EmployeeName = a.FirstName,

                b.Amount,
                b.ModelType,
                b.PeriodTime
            });

    var expense = employeeList.SelectMany(a => a.ExpensesModel, (a, b) => new
            {
                EmployeeNik = a.NIK,
                EmployeeName = a.FirstName,

                b.Amount,
                b.ModelType
            });

    var sumSalary = income.Union(expense);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Union in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483711/union-in-entity-framework)

Comment: How are you expecting the `Union` to work given the first query returns different columns (e.g. Salary) than the second?

Comment: you need to have the same exact properties on both anonymous types to make it work.